# Spring WS Osgi samples

Tags: tomcat, jetty, osgi, spring-ws, springsource-dm-server

We are currently researching OSGI at work and I need to provide a proof of concept on its use with spring dm and spring-ws in the appropriate application server(tomcat / jetty).Does anyone have a example or a tutorial or any links that can help in my research?

I have for the past dew days been looking for some samples on how to implement spring ws in OSGI along with Spring DM.

Any help will be really appreciated.

In the interim I am waiting for my Spring DM in Action book.

Thanks, so much.

Garth

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse [Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/) project, which is based on OSGi and Tomcat with Jetty support in the process of being added, provides a [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/) "Creating an application with Virgo" that leads you through building the [Greenpages](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/download/) sample web application. That may be of interest.